# find ALL mac address related to one Specific IP

Tags: c#, networking, ip-address, mac-address

Is there any way to get ***all MAC*** addresses for just ***one IP*** by c#? I can get just one MAC by ARP calling and I do not want to use SNMP.

e.g. for all ***ports of a switch***, each port has a mac and the whole switch has just one IP. 
thanks

Comment: An IP only have one MAC.  The MAC is built into the Ethernet adapter card and contains the Manufacturer, Model, Serial Number and is unique.  If a PC has more than one Ethernet Adapter it will also have more IP addresses.

Comment: @jdweng - I can't think of any way for you to discover the MAC addresses listening but IP broadcast and multicast do at least exist as concepts. And there's no requirement that each adapter be assigned unique IP addresses either

Comment: No, look we have a cisco switch and it has 8 port, each port has a mac address, but the switch has just one IP, I want to get all mac addresses of the switch by that IP, is it possible? thanks for your response

Comment: You've ruled out SNMP which is likely the only means open to you. Most of the more conventional protocols you're dealing with are there to assist with enabling communication. But since only one MAC address on the switch has any communications *utility* to you (the one to which you're connected), I wouldn't expect any other protocol to be able to find the information.

Comment: !Damien_The_Unbeliever : Can you show me where you can have two adapter using the same IP on Windows?

Comment: @jdweng - I haven't has to set it up for a while but one example would be link aggregation as discussed (and linked further to) from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/336869/59978)

Comment: Windows and Unix handle IP addresses differently.  Your link doesn't specify operating system, but SUPERUSER usually implies unix operating system.   Unix can have multiple IP addresses for same IP.  Windows the IP address is on the network card.  Do not confuse the two OS when referring to IP address.

Comment: @jdweng - fine, I'll follow all of two clicks away from the answer I linked to - [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation#Microsoft_Windows). And no, SUPERUSER doesn't imply unix. There are specific OS exchanges (Ask Ubuntu, Unix & Linux). Superuser is the *generic* user site.

Comment: please help me if there is an answer and don't fight, as @Ron Maupin says in bellow answer , it is not possible

Comment: There is only one mac per IP.  You can have multiple IPs for one MAC.  You can have multiple IPs for each PC and then have more than one MAC per PC.  You can get all addresses for a PC and then PING each IP to get all MAC.  You may get duplicate MAC since more than one IP can have same MAC.  See following code :  string LocalHostName = Dns.GetHostName();IPHostEntryLocalHostIPEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(LocalHostName);IPAddress LocalHostIP = LocalHostIPEntry.AddressList[0];  AddressList is an array and will contain all IP for a PC.

Answer (score 0):

> No, look we have a cisco switch and it has 8 port, each port has a mac
>   address, but the switch has just one IP, I want to get all mac
>   addresses of the switch by that IP, is it possible? thanks for your
>   response

The switch IP address will be assigned to an SVI, and that SVI only has one MAC address associated with it. Each Cisco switch supervisor has 1024 MAC addresses to be used for layer-3 interfaces, but those have nothing to do with the layer-2 switch interfaces.

The MAC addresses on the layer-2 switch interfaces are not associated with the layer-3 switch management interface. The MAC addresses on the layer-2 interfaces are for the link-local layer-2 protocols (e.g. STP, CDP, LLDP, DTP, PAgP, etc.). Those MAC addresses should never be seen off the link for the interface.

Each layer-3 switch interface will be assigned one MAC address by the supervisor. Remember that the layer-3 interfaces on the switch have nothing to do with switching, which is a layer-2 function. The layer-3 switch interfaces are for switch management, and they are like connecting a host to the layer-2 switch.

Comment: So it seems there is not useful answer, yes?, I have been asked by my boss to do this task. Actually in our application each ports of the cisco switch is got by SNMP protocol, but they asked me to show a list of IPs and their related Mac addresses, as I explained in my question. Thank you very much

Comment: As I tried to explain, the MAC addresses on the layer-2 interfaces are _not_ associated with a layer-3 (IP) address. The layer-3 address assigned to a layer-3 interface (SVI) on a switch has only one MAC address associated with it. You are not understanding the difference.

Comment: I understand, thanks. I mean it is not possible to get mac addresses and the switch IP, but consider the MAc address for SVI are the same as first mac address of the ports, at least for our devices it is.

Comment: when I use arp -a command it gives me an IP an a MAC, of all devices, would you tell me what is this MAC? not just for cisco, for all . for cisco you right , it gives the VLAN mac,

Comment: A VLAN is a simply a layer-2 broadcast domain, and it doesn't have a MAC address. The SVI on a switch for a VLAN could have a MAC address. ARP relates a layer-3 (e.g. IP) address to a layer-2 (e.g. MAC) address. Only layer-3 interfaces have ARP tables and respond to ARP requests. I think you need to research your question on [networkengineering.se], which is the proper SE site for understanding networking, and where there are many questions and answers to explain the network layers and MAC addressing.